# error when using core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

hello i'm trying to use core data to read and write user data.
the code i'm using is as follows:

### AppDelegate interface

```
@interface PopAdsAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
@private
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel_;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end
```

the code i'm getting error in is this in the **.m** file:

```
PopAdsAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

this line in specific

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

the **.xcdatamodeld** file i have is called `UserData.xcdatamodeld` and i have entity called "User".

To be honest i don;t know where in the code i should provide the `UserData.xcdatamodeld` file name?!! all i see in the examples is only the entity name!

the error i'm getting is:

> [PopAdsAppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x180d60
>       2011-12-25 13:36:37.008 PopAds2[15645:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PopAdsAppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x180d60'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x3435f8bf 0x345af1e5 0x34362acb 0x34361945 0x342bc680 0x3c87 0x41a9 0x35d6bc39 0x35cc36e9 0x35cc36b3 0x35cc35d5 0x323718a5 0x32366545 0x32366639 0x32366243 0x32366179 0x34333b03 0x343332cf 0x34332075 0x342b54dd 0x342b53a5 0x30b39fcd 0x37736743 0x305d 0x2ff4)
>       terminate called throwing an exceptionkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a new project in Xcode and select the "Core Data" checkbox in the wizard? Xcode will then create a new project for you that uses Core Data. You usually don't have to setup Core Data yourself.

Comment: You do need it in case when you need to add core data functionality to project that already running for a while... :(

Comment: Sure. But then simply copy the code from the template and paste it into your old project and adjust the hardcoded strings. Should be easier for a beginner than doing it from scratch.

Comment: That's a general approach, thought it's better to understand what are you doing instead of just copy/pasting as it lead to better solutions (let's say in case you are also want to pre ship some data, as it was in my project simple copy/paste will miss the target)

Comment: By copy and paste its more likely to get a working solution in this case and then it should be easier to get an understanding of the code since it works. Its much harder to try to understand something that is not working at all. But thats just my opinion. :)

Comment: That's true :) but hey, we aren't looking for easy ways ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your appDelegate have no managedObjectContext method as it seems from the error.

**Edit:**

Take a look at those links:
[Ray Wenderlich Blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)
[Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php)
[Mobile Tuts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)
 
And if those aren't enought, you could always [Google it](http://www.google.co.il/search?ie=UTF-8&q=core%20data%20tutorial) :)

Comment: sorry but I'm totally new to this. can you provide a solution or a link to a solution? thanks

Comment: i did synthesize some object as @luxquarta suggested but now getting an error saying: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name i noticed that this line NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; does not initialize the object context! any idea

Comment: Actually you don't need to synthesize those objects inside an app delegate as there should be methods that initialize those objects. if you are synthesize them, then those methods are not called and those objects are not initialized. Try to create a new project with core data enabled as @cmk suggest and take a look at how the stuff works.

Comment: If I remember right, the default implementation (the one that comes with the core data template provided by Apple) synthesizes the managedObjectContext and managedModel but overrides the setters to lazily initialize the private attributes.

Comment: Oh, I've incorrectly announced my idea. What I've meant is that if you forgot to provide such custom implementation, the default (synthesized) getter does not initialize anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not synthesized your property

Add

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

to your AppDelegate.m file

**EDIT**
I thought you just forgot to initialize your property but it seems that you are just beginning to learn CoreData.

The more efficient approach to learn how to initialize CoreData is to study the code of the defaut implementation provided by Apple. Create a new project and in the wizard chose to use CoreData. You will get a working code and see the two setters being overridden. At their first call the private attributes are initialized. This is lazy loading, initialize when first need it.

You should also read the [CoreData starting point](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316) and especially [CoreData programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html)

Comment: @synthesize managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext_; if we are talking about it. And do not forget to do the same for other properties as well :)

Comment: yes i noticed that, i did synthesize them but now getting an error saying:
'+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name
i noticed that this line
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
does not initialize the object context!

Comment: [self managedObjectContext] does not initialize things. It's just a method returning a managedObjectContext. If you haven't set it before it will return nil.

Comment: I would advise you to create a new xCode project using a template provided by Apple. For example Empty Application (the last one in the application section). On the second screen of the wizard tick Use CoreData. Open the delegate and look at the setters (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext   and - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel